# Chrome not sending headers with foreign characters

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post, http-headers

I have a problem with Chrome not sending headers containing "special characters", such as the Swedish ÅÄÖ. If I strip these special characters it all works fine. Here's a simple example:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/echo/html/',
      headers: {
          "SomeHeader":"ÅÄÖ" // This header will be removed.
          "SomeOtherHeader":"ABC" // This header will be sent.
      },
      data: {
         foo: 'bar',
         delay: 1
      }
  })
  
  .fail(function(data){
      alert("Error!");
  })
  .done(function(data) { 
      alert("Success!");
  });
```

When looking at the network-tab in Chrome it's obvious that one header is missing. I tried setting the `Content-Type` to: `application/json; charset=UTF-8` without any luck.
The error occurs in Chrome (85.0.4183.121 x64). Edge sends the header, but with empty content (!?). IE11 and Firefox sends the header with all it's content.

[image]

Here is a reproducable fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qr8j0cgo/

How can I tell Chrome (and all the other browsers) to send the header containing my special characters?
As an extra requirement my real world problem involves a content-type with `multipart/form-data` and boundary.

I know that I can encode the characters with practically any encoding (even base64) and thus make a workaround. But I cannot change anything on the server, so the request needs to be the same (or at least interpreted the same as before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the Chrome extension [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj). When disabling it everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am running on Google Chrome 88.0.4324.96 (Officiell version) (64 bitar).

I would bet on corporate network filter.
[image: Working]